# java setDate on mySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I have two sql date that from a function parameter:

```
public void aaa (java.sql.Date sqlDate1, java.sql.Date sqlDate2)
```

inside the function is:

```
String sql = "SELECT ROOM_TYPE_ID , COUNT(ROOM_ID) AS Available_Room_Quantity FROM ROOM " +
             "WHERE Room_ID NOT IN (SELECT ROOM_ID FROM ROOM_RECORD WHERE START_DATE<=? AND END_DATE>=? ) "+
             "GROUP BY ROOM_TYPE_ID";

statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setDate(1, sqlDate1);
statement.setDate(2, sqlDate2);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

while(rs.next())
{

    String first = rs.getString("Available_Room_Quantity");
    String last = rs.getString("ROOM_TYPE_ID");

    System.out.print("ROOM_TYPE_ID: " + first);
    System.out.print(" Available_Room_Quantity" + last + "\n");
}
rs.close();
```

it have error when runnning time, both startdate and enddate declare as date in mysql.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near '? AND END_DATE>=? ) GROUP BY ROOM_TYPE_ID' at
line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1062)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4226)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4158)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2834)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2783)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1569)
```

Comment: Try making sure that there is whitespace before and after each h question mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass query again. You have already passes it at the time of `PreparedStatement` construction:

```
statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

Just remove query string from `executeQuery()` method.

If you pass it again then `?` will not be replaced by actual values and hence you are getting invalid query string syntax error near `? AND END_DATE>=?`

It should be

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery( );
                                      ^----------- Remove query string from here
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your sql query two times:

***Once here:***

```
statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

***And another here:***

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

You need to pass it only once. So change the second line:

***From this:***

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

***To this:***

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

***`So that you can avoid the confusion in the date region, where the placeholders (?) wont be replaced with their provided values (sqlDate1, sqlDate2).`***